# convert string to integer in php pdo

Tags: php, postgresql, oop, pdo

How do I convert string data type into integer with php pdo? I have tried using `PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PDO::PARAM_STR` but `return false` and error when I tried to insert data to `postgresql`. Is there any way to solve this?

here the codes :

function create(){

```
    // to get time-stamp for 'created' field

    $this->getTimestamp();
    //write query
    $query = "INSERT INTO 
                " . $this->table_name . " 
            (id_barang, nama_barang, harga_beli, harga_jual, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id_barang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->nama_barang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->harga_beli, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $this->harga_jual, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $this->created);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

it return false and i'm using alert if function create() false. 
harga_beli and harga_jual are integer data type in postgresql. in html form i'm using javascript function to separate the zero. example : 60.000, and the numbers should be an integer on database.

Comment: if you have an error, give the error + description in your question - it's always useful as you ask about it. also show an excerpt of your code so it's more clear what you do. see the help center for more tips about writing your question(s): http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: The PDO database driver will automatically 'coerce' the PHP parameter to the appropriate database type when it is used. i.e. if you say PDO::PARAM_INT and the value is a string representing a valid integer then it will work fine.

Comment: @Sofffia i have edited my question. please help if you know something :)

Comment: @RyanVincent it return false when i executed them.

Comment: If `$stmt->execute()` returns false there is an error with your query. Use `$error = $this->conn->errorInfo(); var_dump($error);` to debug your SQL problem. Alternatively you can use `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to get exceptions on SQL errors (which is the preferred way in OOP).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function :

```
echo intval('042');                   // 42
```

Comment: i'm using oop pdo so echo the variable in that way doesnt work i think.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can leave it up to PDO to do the conversion
2. If execute is false check for errors
3. The proper way to know if it is successful is to check the affected row

---

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id_barang);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $this->nama_barang);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $this->harga_beli);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $this->harga_jual);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $this->created);

$stmt->execute() or die('error:'.$this->conn->errorInfo());

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the error result is :

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\bismillah\objects\barang.php on line 40
error:Array